# AddObject in TStringList

Tags: c++, c++builder, tstringlist

This is the first time I use `AddObject` method in C++ Builder 6 in a `TStringList`
but I can not add an integer to the object list for example. Of course I did it by means of casting different types. But it's not what I want. Please help me do it simpler
and why the objects must be `Tobject*` in object list
this is my simple program...

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int r=random(100+1);
    TStringList *mylist=new TStringList;
    mylist->AddObject("r",(TObject *)r);
    int i=mylist->IndexOf("r");
    int a=(int)(mylist->Objects[i]);
    cout<<a<<endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm tempted to offer the suggestion of using a compiler that isn't over a decade old and is standards-compliant, because this kind of lackadaisical casting is ugly as hell.

Comment: This isn't a compiler issue?  Its more of a class selection/library  issue.  It can be resolved using the same techniques you'd use with any modern c++ compiler.

Comment: Like using a `std::vector` of struct, or a `std::map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why the objects must be Tobject*

Because of Borland's design of VCL.

> mylist->AddObject("r",(TObject *)r);

Do not do this, because there's no guarantee that `TStringList` wouldn't call some methods of `TObject*` inside `AddObject`. For example it can call `objectName()` or `incrementReference()` (I know, that there's no `TStringList::incrementReference()` but it's just an example).

IMHO, all that you need is [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    int r=random(100+1);
    std::map< AnsiString, int > myList;
    myList[ "r" ] = r;
    int a = myList[ "r" ];
}
```

Comment: What if there are duplicate strings in the list?  And what do you reckon the performance of this is like in terms of memory consumption and speed?

Comment: If there's dublicates, then OP can use `multimap`. As if OP uses VCL I think he doesn't think about performance :)

Comment: Prior to XE5, C++Builder did not support any mobile development, so `TStringList` did not call any methods on its `TObject*` pointers, so it was safe to store whatever you wanted, just type-cast.  It worked just fine. However, in XE5 and later, on iOS and Android platforms only, ARC (automatic reference counting) is used for Delphi-style (`TObject`-derived) objects, so it is no longer safe to store non-object pointers in a `TStringList`, or anything else that uses `TObject*` pointers, due to compiler-managed reference counting. So use another container instead, such as `std::map`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `std::map` or other suitable container instead, eg:

```
#pragma hdrstop

#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <map>

#pragma argsused

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int r = random(100+1);
    std::map<std::string, int> mylist;
    mylist["r"] = r;
    int a = mylist["r"];
    cout << a << std::endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very ugly but the cast will work fine.  The pragmatic approach is to stick with that method if you must use TStringList.

If you wanted, you could add TObject derived wrappers that hold 'int's to another vector and use these pointers but it require more code to maintain that second list, is more prone to errors and a lot slower.

Alternatively new these wrappers and add them to the stringlist and then manage deletion of the objects manually. This is error prone.

The best approach may be to ditch TStringList if that is possible.  Use a struct/class or a std::pair and std::vector or std::deque.

e.g.

```
typedef std::pair<AnsiString, int> MyValue;
typedef std::vector<MyValue> MyValueList;

MyValueList list;
list.push_back(MyValue("hello", 1));

AnsiString const& s = list[0].first;
int i = list[0].second;
```

Comment: Creating `TObject`-based wrappers would only be necessary when using C++Builder XE5 or later for iOS/Android mobile development, due to ARC. On other platforms, ARC is not used, so type-casts are safe.